# I can't apply the gradle 6.x plugin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

It says I'm supposed to write:

```
plugins {
id "com.gradle.enterprise" version "3.5"
}

gradleEnterprise {
server = "https://gradle-enterprise.mycompany.com"
}
```

On the **settings.gradle** file according to:
https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/gradle-plugin/

But then I get an error saying:

`2: Only Project build scripts can contain plugins {} blocks`

Comment: Is that your entire settings.gradle? Please post that.

Comment: Sure my entire settings.gradle file is 
`include ':app', ':lib'

plugins {
    id "com.gradle.enterprise" version "3.5"
}
gradleEnterprise {
    server = "https://gradle-enterprise.mycompany.com"
}`

Comment: Can you try putting the plugins block as the first line in your settings.gradle before any other?

Comment: I tried just now and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Have you tired putting this in your build.gradle just out of interest?

Comment: Yes and it says it gives me the following error: `The Gradle Enterprise plugin must be applied to the settings (was applied to a project)`

Comment: Interesting and you know there are 2 `settings.gradle` files, one is for the project (under `Gradle Scripts` folder) that is where your changes are?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, My android studio was still building so duplicated scripts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I seem to have this working.

Please ensure `plugins` and and `gradleEnterprise` blocks are the first and second lines in the file respectively or you will get an error:

`settings.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.enterprise' version '3.5'
}

gradleEnterprise {
    // configuration
}

include ':app'
rootProject.name = "My Application"
```

My Current Gradle plugin versions are as follows (<kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Project Structure</kbd>):

[image]

And it all builds fine.

**PS**: I was getting an error: T*his version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.1 or newer.* I had to update my android studios to the latest as well (4.1.1) and all worked a charm.

Comment: Thank you, well a deal is a deal I'll reward you the bounty. However the app I'm trying to use still doesn't work I'm afraid. :(

Comment: Oh it says I have to wait 22 hours to award the bounty. Well the app I'm trying to run is this one https://github.com/cosmostation/cosmostation-mobile but again you already got the bounty. Thank you.

Comment: @pete Thanks man, please do post a new question for any other problem you are having and send me a link here and I'll try have a look at it for you, but at least if I don't know the answer someone else might, that's why I'd suggest posting a new question.